# Could someone explain this SQL syntax error?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to write an sql statement for sqlite along the following lines, where I only need those three fields from the tasks field:

```
select (tasks.id, tasks.title, tasks.comment) from 
tasks inner join contexts_tasks on tasks.id = contexts_tasks.task_id 
where (contexts_tasks.context_id = 0);
```

`select *` returns fields that I'm not interested in including, but I just get this vague error message when I try to do it the way I did above:

```
SQL error: near ",": syntax error
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Any explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the parentheses from `(tasks.id, tasks.title, tasks.comment)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, remove the parenthesis from the fields in the `SELECT` clause.  Someone who knows more about the inner workings of SQL can feel free to correct/elaborate, but I think that the query parser treats parenthetical expressions as something to be evaluated.  Note, for example, the parenthesis around your `WHERE` clause, which evaluates to a boolean.  The column names by themselves don't evaluate to anything but a syntax error.  If, on the other hand, you placed a sub-`SELECT` or otherwise evaluatable expression within parenthesis in your `SELECT` clause, it would parse it.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have brackets around the items in your SELECT list.  `SELECT a, b, c FROM d WHERE e = 1`.